# What NFL teams have been shutout in consecutive games?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

Miami Dolphins were almost shutout for the 2nd consecutive game. A TD as time expired last week vs. Jets are only points Miami has in last 2 games.

Has a team ever been shutout in consecutive games?

Answer (score 4):

There are many teams who have been shutout in consecutive games. Searching after 1970 [Oakland Raiders](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/rai/) had been shutout in 3 games consecutively. While the record is of 7 consecutive games shared by [Louisville Colonels](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/lou/) and [Hammond Pros](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/ham/). The most recent consecutive shutout was of [Cleveland Browns](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/cle/).

Using team streak finder of [pro-football-reference.com](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/) the table generated is as follows:

[image: oakland] 
[(Source)](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/team_streak_finder.cgi?request=1&streak_type=games&year_min=1970&year_max=2017&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&streak_event=points&streak_event_gtlt=eq&streak_num=0&streak_event_gtlt_2=gt&streak_length=2)

Complete table:

[image: record]
[(Source)](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/team_streak_finder.cgi?request=1&streak_type=games&year_min=1920&year_max=2017&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&streak_event=points&streak_event_gtlt=eq&streak_num=0&streak_event_gtlt_2=gt&streak_length=2)

Most recent:

[image: recent]

Comment: +1.  Most recent occurrence of back-to-back shutouts was the [Cleveland Browns in December 2008](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/team_streak_finder.cgi?request=1&streak_type=games&year_min=1970&year_max=2017&game_type=R&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&streak_event=points&streak_event_gtlt=eq&streak_num=0&streak_event_gtlt_2=gt&streak_length=2).